# google ads bigquery data transfer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I am creating bigquery data transfer service for google ads data.
the data transfer service was created successfully.
while retrieving the data the transfer service is getting failed with below error.

```
generic::permission_denied: Error while processing subtask:  The caller does not have permission Raw error response from Google Ads API: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "errors": [ { "message": "The caller does not have permission", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "debugInfo": "detail: \"[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::permission_denied: User doesn\\'t have permission to access customer. Note: If you\\'re accessing a client customer, the manager\\'s customer id must be set in the \\'login-customer-id\\' header. See https://developers.google.com/google-
```

I checked the google documentation the user should have permissions in google ads and GCP as well

in my case both of them are different user,for example my email id in GCP is different and my email id in google ads is different.

once i setup the transfer service i updated the credentials with update credentials option.
which mean i authorized retransfer using the email id which has access to google ads.

the update credentials step was success didn't throw any error,

even after this my data transfer is failing with same error.

is it not at possible use different user to authorize google ads data transfer?

how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Check if the BigQuery user defined in the Data Transfer configuration has an access to Google Ads - if not apply the proper permissions on the Google Ads side.

Comment: in my case both are different users

Comment: So that's the answer, why you get the missing permissions error. Could you switch the Data Transfer user to use the privilaged one?

Comment: As per my organization setup 
the id which is access to GCP is don't have access to google ads same way the id which has access to google ads doesn't access to GCP.

is it not at all possible use different user to authorize google ads data transfer?